# Generic Multiplication of Different Types

Tags: .net, generics, f#

In simple words, I want to implement a function like that:

```
let myfunction (scalar : float) (quantities : ''T list) = 
    List.fold (fun acc quantity -> acc + quantity * scalar)
        LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero<_>
            quantities : 'T
```

Note that I am multiplying a value of generic type `'T` and a float value (`quantity * scalar`) which should return a value of type `'T`. For example, multiplying a `Point` by a scalar result in a `Point`.

I cannot make F# understand that the multiplication `quantity * scalar` should result in a value of type `'T`. I tried `LanguagePrimitives.MultiplyDynamic`, but it seems that this function is reserved to be used by the F# compiler.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason to specialize to the case where scalar is a float?  I think your best bet is to generalize even further:

```
let inline myfunction scalar quantities =  
    List.fold (fun acc quantity -> acc + quantity * scalar)
        LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero<_>
        quantities
```

Comment: Nice, the inline resolved my problems. Amazing how easy you can write generalized code in F#! I am getting passionate for this language everyday!